# Heavy tailed discrete distribution infinite mean

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm looking for an example of a discrete distribution with infinite mean $f_n = P(X = n)$ for $n=1,2..$ such that the sequence $r_n = \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty}f_k$ satisfies the relation $$r_n = L(n)n^{-\alpha},$$ where $0 < \alpha < 1$ and $L(x)$ is a slowly varying function. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "slowly varying"?

Comment: I mean $L$ that is positive and for every $\lambda > 0,$ $L(\lambda x)/L(x) \to 1$ as $x \to \infty.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy example meeting your requirements might be to define $L(n)=c$ constant with $0 \lt c \le 1$ and $$f_n=P(X=n)=c (n-1)^{-\alpha} - c n^{-\alpha} \text{ for } n \ge 2$$ $$f_1=P(X=1)=1-c.$$

A more well known example might be the [zeta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_distribution) with $$f_n=P(X=n)=\dfrac{n^{-\alpha-1}}{\zeta(\alpha+1)}$$ where $\zeta(x)$ is the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) - for example $\zeta(1.5) \approx 2.6123753$